# Template forwarding calls to a member's method

Tags: c++, templates, reference, sfinae

Consider the following:

```
template <typename type> class my_wrapper
{
  type _;

  template <typename... types, typename std :: enable_if <has_my_method_callable_with_the_following_types <type, types...> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> void my_method(types... items)
  {
    _.my_method(items...);
  }
};
```

Where, as you can imagine, `has_my_method_callable_with_the_following_types` is some kind of SFINAE struct that allows me to determine if `type` has a method that can be called with those types.

As you can easily see, the example above basically forwards all the calls to `my_method` down to `_`. Well. *Nearly* all of them. What happens if I do:

```
class my_type
{
  void my_method(int & x)
  {
    x++;
  }
};

my_wrapper <my_type> my_wrapped;

int x;
my_wrapped.my_method(x);
```

Clearly the above will not work, as `x` would be passed to the function by copy while `my_type :: my_method` accepts it by reference. So I wonder: is there any way to work around this issue? Of course I could do:

```
template <typename... types, typename std :: enable_if <has_my_method_callable_with_the_following_types <type, types & ...> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> void my_method(types & ... items)
{
  _.my_method(items...);
}
```

But then symmetrically I will have problems when I am passing, say, `int` literals that I cannot take by reference but that would be perfectly acceptable by some `my_type :: my_method(int x)`.

How can I work around this problem? I would like to seamlessly forward all the calls to `my_wrapper <type> :: my_method` to `type :: my_method`.

**Pirates beware**: I cannot use inheritance, so please don't suggest that! :)

Comment: You're looking for what's called 'perfect forwarding'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *exactly* what perfect forwarding and forwarding references were introduced for:

```
template <
  typename... types,
  typename std :: enable_if <has_my_method_callable_with_the_following_types <type, types...> :: value> :: type * = nullptr
> void my_method(types&&... items)
{
  _.my_method(std::forward<types>(items)...);
}
```

How this works:

There's a special rule in the language which says that when deducing a `T` in a `T&&` construct, and the argument used for deduction is an lvalue of type `U`, then `T` is deduced as `U&` instead of `U`.

The net effect is that when a parameter is a forwarding reference (`T&&` for a deduced `T`), it will either be an lvalue reference (if the argument is an lvalue), or an rvalue reference (if the argument is an rvalue). `std::forward<T>` will then cast it back to lvalue or rvalue as appropriate.

Comment: What is the difference between calling `_.my_method(std :: forward <types> (items)...)` and `_.my_method(items...)`?

Comment: @MatteoMonti Don't forget that a named rvalue reference is an lvalue. The version without `std::forward` will fail if `my_method` accepts an rvalue reference (or a move-only type by value).